# Ubuntu certified laptops Intel WiFi

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, intel-wireless, hardware-certification

I see `Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga` at the Ubuntu certified list (http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201602-41481/). As I understand, everything works on this laptop out of the box. And I see that it uses `Intel Wireless 8260` as a WiFi-module. Does it mean that theoretically I can **expect** that WiFi will work on any laptop with this WiFi-module?

For example, I cannot find `Lenovo Yoga 900 13"` in that list, but this laptop uses the same `Intel Wireless 8260` module. So, I can install Ubuntu 16.04 on `Yoga 900` and WiFi definitely will work, right? Or it's just my sweet dreams? ;-)